# Need to remove an external js file from footer in mobile

Tags: jquery

I need to remove a specific external js file from the footer if it detects mobile. Can you have suggestion for that? I tried a code but it didn't work.

Here is the code:

```
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {

    $('body').remove( "http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Before-After-Image-Slider-Plugin-imgSlider/js/imgslider.js" );

}
```

Comment: Maybe `$('body script[src="http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Before-After-Image-Slider-Plugin-imgSlider/js/imgslider.js"]').remove()`. Not sure if thats actually going to work as the script is probably already loaded by that itme.

Comment: No it has some errors may be! I cannot save this!

Answer (score 1):

When you call .remove on the $('body'), you're telling it to remove a string. That's not going to work. You would need to tell the browser instead to remove the actual script element.

However, that still wont solve your problem. Once a script has been loaded, it's functions and values are in memory - and removing the script element will not remove those functions/values from memory.

I suggest you take a different approach, and do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if(!(/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) ) {
    var script = $("<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Before-After-Image-Slider-Plugin-imgSlider/js/imgslider.js' />");
    $('head').append( script );
  }        
});
```

Basically, use javascript to only load the script if it is not a mobile device.

edit: Also, it's bad practice to depend on scripts on other domains. Go download that script and host it yourself!

Comment: `<script src..` not `<script href`.. apart from that, good solution.

Comment: Thanks! But I want to remove it for mobile...so append will work for that?

Comment: No - I'm suggesting a different approach. Rather than removing it for mobile (because removing it will do nothing, it's already been loaded!) just load it for all non-mobile browsers.

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
var x= $(window).width()+"px";
  if( x > 640) {
  alert(x);
    var script = $("<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Before-After-Image-Slider-Plugin-imgSlider/js/imgslider.js' />");
    $('head').append( script );
  }        
});

Answer (score 0):

.remove can remove DOM object for which is called or child selector.

```
.remove( [selector ] )
```

http://....  is not selector. You need to indicate specific element.
The easiest option would be to add id attribute to script tag. Yes, it is allowed.  Then you can select by ID.

code will be like:

jquery:
    $('body').remove('#removeonmobile');

You can of course try to create selector using :contains but it may be a little more challenging.

BTW. better option may be to not include this script on mobile, and implement it in server side. jQuery is run after page is loaded, so script will be in memory already - it doesn't make sense to remove script after loading page.

Comment: Yeah - removing the script element isn't going to remove it from memory. Ideally it's just not included in the initial page (done serverside) but if that's not an option, then the right move is to just dynamically load it for all non-mobile devices.